# Is not this contradictory about transfinite numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

The $\omega$ is defined as the *smallest* number which is bigger than all natural numbers, hence $\omega \not\in \mathbb N$. According to this, $\omega - 1$ must be in $\mathbb N$ but since $\mathbb N$ is an inductive set, it must also include $\omega$ and this contradicts with our assumption.

What is the problem with this reasoning?

Comment: There is no $\omega-1$. Subtraction is defined only for *finite* ordinal numbers.

Comment: @bof It may not matter for the problem at hand, but isn't $\alpha \mapsto \alpha-1$ well-defined for all successor ordinals, so the problem is just that $\omega$ is a limit ordinal?  (certainly more general subtraction is harder to nail down)

Comment: There's no such thing as $\omega-1$. Why not? By definition saying $\omega-1=\alpha$ means $\alpha+1=\omega$, and there is no such $\alpha$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I should have said, there's no way to extend subtraction to infinite ordinals *that makes sense of the OP's argument.* Ordinal subtraction is tricky because of non-commutativity. It's true that, whenever $\alpha\le\beta$, the equation $\alpha+x=\beta$ has a unique solution for $x$. So the equation $1+x=\omega$ has the unique solution $x=\omega$, and indeed $1+\omega=\omega$, but $\omega+1\ne\omega$. (Of course you know all this, I'm writing it out for the OP's benefit.)

Comment: All of that looks like a good answer @bof.